# Driving low voltage P-MOS N-MOS half bridge with dead time control, without bootstrap and one control line

Tags: stepper-motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver

I should need a driver of a PMOS NMOS bridge with dead control controlled by a one line from the microcontroller (because I have to use several PWM lines) that inserts a dead time control to avoid both mosfets conducts at the same time. The diagram is this:
[image: PMOS-NMOS driver]

I wondered to do this because I do not need floating power supply and there are P-MOS 3x3mm that conduct 64A like NVTFS9D6P04M8L

Comment: So what you are asking for is someone to find a driver that supports PMOS/NMOS with dead time control with one signal in?
Why not use two standard driver with an inverter and a buffer connected to the same PWM signal from the µC? or just use two NMOS ?

Comment: Because I want have dead time control to avoid both mosfets be switched at the same time and also drive 100% duty cycle, that is not possible using bootstrap. Using two N mosfets in the past was a good idea because it didn't exist any good P-MOS but there are very good now.  NOTE: connect an inverter and a buffer to N and P mosfets IS A VERY BAD IDEA because you activate both mosfets at the same time making short circuit

Comment: you can choose a driver with integrated deadtime control I missed that little thing out

Answer (score 3):

From a comment by the OP: -

> *I want have dead time control to avoid both mosfets be switched at the
> same time and also drive 100% duty cycle*

Use an anti-shoot-through logic circuit like this: -

[image]

This is suitable when the top MOSFET is P channel and the lower MOSFET is N channel. The dead-band produced is roughly capacitance x resistance. Use Schmitt trigger input devices.

For converting to a 12.5 volt rail, there are plenty of MOSFET drivers to choose from made by the usual manufacturers.