# How to make a deadtime circuit in a time of great shortage?

Tags: pwm, gate-driving

I found the only isolated gate driver on the market! It's all perfect, only doesn't have the deadtime circuit - the other part number is out of stock.

I am willing to change the layout and add my own circuit, but it should be cheap, it's a big batch. It should also be reliable for the same reason.

I thought about logic and delays with an RC circuit (has to be at least 200nsec, so not just a buffer for the delay,) but it seems odd.

Are there other ideas?

[2EDF7275K driver datasheet](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/INFN/INFN-S-A0008993695/INFN-S-A0008993695-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0)

The current decision is to go with a logic buffer and a small (160MHz) filter on the command lines.

[image]

Comment: What are the requirements of your gate driver?

Comment: I know of at least several isolated gate drivers...IXYS has some new strange self-powered opto ones, Analog Devices Icouplers and Allegro's opto gate drivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Driving low voltage P-MOS N-MOS half bridge with dead time control, without bootstrap and one control line](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517113/driving-low-voltage-p-mos-n-mos-half-bridge-with-dead-time-control-without-boot)

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy the original part was UCC21225, the new one is from Infineon, all the same, but no death time.

Comment: @DKNguyen i know, can't find stock.

Comment: @Andyaka i thought about exactly that, but i don't know, feels a bit odd. In PWM the accuracy matters, RC filter feels a bit inacurate

Comment: @TQQQ Use NP0 and 0.1% resistors. And diodes. You aren't using an MCU?

Comment: I am using an MCU wich can make both high and low. But the PCB is huge, and i am a bit afraid of EMI spikes. With a single PWM input gate driver there was no problem at all. But with no dead time protection- i don't know, it's a risk

Comment: I'm not sure I see the risk. Just do the deadtime in the MCU's PWM module. If EMI is enough to fire gates then you have bigger problems since everything else is going glitch too. Deal with the EMI through layout. How long is long? Why are your gate driver so far from the gates? That's the EMI *causing* problem, not dead time.

Comment: could rarely catch spikes on the long lines. another way could be using differential lines, but it gets too crazy.

Comment: the gate drivers are next to the gates, the long lines are the digital, between mcu and gate drivers. about 20cm at the longest.

Comment: Oh so the dead time you are talking about isn't RCD in the gate line to make the turn-n slower than the turn-off time? You should edit that in to make your post clear.

Comment: "Are there other ideas?"  Here are two wild and crazy ideas:  a) Post your schematic.  b)  tell us the part number of the gate driver you found.

Comment: @AnalogKid Indeed. Gate drivers typically have glitch filtering in their inputs.

Comment: OH - I just thought of another great idea:  Post your schematic.

Comment: @AnalogKid the part is 2EDF7275KXUMA1. I will not post the schematic (sorry, NDA)- simply trust me there is nothing interesting.

Comment: It has Schmidt trigger inputs. I would maybe just add series termination resistors, but on both ends. If you're real worried leave room for a cap to ground next to the input, but do not populate. This has nothing to do with deadtime so I don't know why you call it that. It's just filtering.

Comment: you see, if a spike strong enough to cause shoot-through happens once a year, i am risking here the whole batch of products and a lot of money and reputation. Really i wouldn't ask for ideas if it wasn't such risk :)))

Comment: Then you should run tests by inducing spikes to see if it needs to be populated. Or ferrite beads instead of a resistor next to the input. But with ferrite beads....can do more harm than good if the wrong one. Fairly interchangeable footprint though with a resistor.

Comment: i know, i know.... only i can do tests after the production, can't do before. so i need to prepare all options... and again, reducing risk is not the same as being protected from when it happens. not getting a spike in the lab doesn't mean i will not get it in the field. so deat time protection seems the obvious solution

Comment: This isn't deadtime...

Comment: what is it then?

Comment: [The datasheet of the part that has the order number in it that you quoted](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/INFN/INFN-S-A0008993695/INFN-S-A0008993695-1.pdf?hkey=6D3A4C79FDBF58556ACFDE234799DDF0)  shows dead time control. This MAY not be in all versions. You do yourself less than zero good by not being specific about the part you are using to a level of detail where we can understand the actual question.

Comment: Sorry, but I have read the datasheet, clearly more than you have. The part has NO dead time protection. Really, I wouldn't ask if that was not the case. I find this type of arrogance very bizarre. The question is more general than a specific part. What if someone else faces a similar problem with something else?

Comment: @TQQQ You quoted part number 2EDF7275KXUMA1. That's an order code. On page 29 of the datasheet in the link I cited it shows that order code and says the actual part number is 2EDF7275K.  Page 3 says your part is in an LGA13 package. Page 13 shows an 2EDF7235K with dead time control. It APPEARS that if you change to a 2EDF7235K it MAY do what you want. || [Digikey reports](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/2EDF7235KXUMA1/8627155?s=N4IgTCBcDa4KIBEBiB2MBmArAaRAXQF8g)  having 3832 in stock. Others may have also. ||

Comment: You now show a completely different IC in your question than you mentioned in comments. Please show actual part numbers of interest and other known information in the question. If your NDA does not allow enough information for us to know what the real question is then we cannot answer it with any certainty. || Questions are often specific enough that answers have to be specific also. Providing generic all encompassing answers often results in no answer at all.

Comment: Sadly digikey stock is not enough... I mean, this is not supposed to be a purchasing discussion, is it? Why do you have this urge to explain how wrong i am? I already see that no new ideas come up here, and it's fine.

Comment: Funny how much time you spend trying to humiliate me.

Comment: @TQQQ The word you were looking for is "help". | I advised you that a driver with dead time control BUT otherwise identical to what you had nominated existed, and that a supplier had some stock.  I do not know how many you wanted but I suggested that if Digikey has stock others may also. | If you cannot distinguish between humiliation and help, and between arrogance and attempts to assist then help or assistance may not be possible. | I'm a site admin - my intention is to be as helpful as reasonably possible. If you follow what I advised above it may be useful to you.

Comment: be accurate. may or may not. usually if i would bring up digikey, you would deem the question off-topic. so as a site admin you should be more consistent. and as a human being, start with a little trust, that people asking questions do know generally what they are talking about. the kind of help that starts with "You do yourself less than zero good " is called patronage. Something tells me in a real life setting you wouldn't talk to me like that

Comment: Like I said earlier, it's just filtering of the gate driver input. Deadtime would be disallowing a signal to turn on both high and low side MOSFETs at the same time. In your case they can both fix the problem, but they aren't the same solution. Filtering ultimately will allow both high and low side to turn on if the spurious signal is strong enough (or if you just command both to turn on). Deadtime control would not but is also way more complicated.

Comment: Yes, that i know. So i settle on filter + logic. One of the possible problems is software bugs. For instance, breakpoints inside interrupt may cause both commands to go high, i am not sure why exactly. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Comment: https://youtu.be/-HLp_6xfz5Y?si=Fsb3bIOBNehhneIK This is how to implement a dead time in hardware using a comparator, AND gate and RC time delay.

Answer (score 1):

> has to be at least 200nsec, so not just a buffer for the delay

Not all logic is as fast as you think :) The CD4000 logic family will produce the delays you want if you run it from a low enough voltage. Since you seem to be running 3V logic, the CD4000B gates will have delay in the right ballpark without additional RC components. You can use that delay to produce dead-time.

Comment: alright, that's an idea indeed, thank you! though i am not sure it's more accurate than an RC filter :)))

Comment: Whatever you’re using that driver for is probably running closed loop. The exact duration of the dead time is perhaps not as critical as you think :)

Comment: true... still, this is a type of things that if it does have an effect, it's hard to understand what's going on and fix it.